# SQL - Show only records created 4 days ago - Nothing between

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to contact people who were added to the database exactly 4 days ago - however my query brings up everyone who has been added within the last 4 days.

```
WHERE DateAdded BETWEEN GetDate() - 4 AND GetDate() - 3
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It's a custom SQL database based on Windows Access I believe

Comment: "exactly 4 days ago" means Feb 11 2020 8:48:03.003 for me now. Is that REALLY what you desired? Because you meant "that were added anytime during the day 4 days ago"? Words matter - how you state your requirements will help you write the logic and help others understand your goal.

Comment: Good point, I will keep this in mind 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getdate()` -- in databases that support it -- has a time component.  So I think you want:

```
WHERE DateAdded BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -4, CAST(GetDate() as DATE)) AND
                        DATEADD(day, -3, CAST(GetDate() as DATE))
```

You can also express this as:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, DateAdded, GetDate()) = 4
```

However, this version will not use indexes for filtering.

Comment: If It works, @rodm92 , you should mark it as the solution, to let future readers know it was helpful, and other users know th question has been answered. You also get reputation, which as a new user is really important to getting those initial privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind declaring variables then one way to do this is:

```
DECLARE @startdate date = DATEADD(DAY, -4, getdate())
DECLARE @enddate   date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startdate)

SELECT * FROM ...
WHERE DateAdded >= @startdate
  AND DateAdded < @enddate
```

This avoids the inclusive properties of BETWEEN, meaning you don't include the next day at 00:00:00.000 time.  It's also sargable.